# Deleting duplicate data

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-tables

I've created a database named "Retail Stores" and I've created table names of the following: "store", "account", "order" "store_salesperson", and "store_warehouse_shipper. Please see the photo of the table below:

[image]

My question is how can you produce or integrate "hub1" as one data ONLY or ONE result only on the HUB column without affecting the other columns of the tables?

What I mean is the number of stores, name, # of Orders, Total Order Size, # of Boxes, Latitude, Longitude still appears the same result but "Hub1" data will only appear only once on the Hub Column.

Here is the code of my self-taught exercise:

```
   select (s.id) as '# of stores', 
    s.name,
   (a1.display_name) as hub,
   count(o.id) as '# of orders',
   sum(total_product_cost) as 'Total Order Size',
   sum(o.no_of_boxes) as '# of boxes',
   s.point_y as latitude,
   s.point_x as longitude

   from `order` as o 
   join store_warehouse_shipper as sws on sws.id = o.associate_id
   join store as s on s.id = sws.store_id
   join store_salesperson as ss on ss.store_id = s.id
   join account as a1 on a1.id=ss.salesperson_account_id
   left join store_salesperson as ss1 on ss1.store_id = s.id and 
   ss1.id>ss.id 

   where
   date(delivered_by) = curdate()
   and a1.display_name like '%hub%'

   group by s.id, a1.id
   order by a1.id ASC
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want the output to look like. Are you saying you want it to hide the value in the 'hub' column if it is the same as the previous row?

Comment: I need to have the output where each 'hub' row data will only appear once. For example, 'hub1', 'hub2', 'hub3, and so on will only appear once on the column. In other words, I don't need a repetitive row data under the Hub column.

Comment: I'm afraid that hasn't helped me understand, because you've used *exactly the same wording* that you already used in the question. The 4 rows which show hub1 all show different data in the other columns, which implies that each of those rows has value in being there. Can you edit the photo of the actual results and post a second version to show what you want?

Comment: I'm wondering why you can't understand the point of my question? I already said that I don't "need a repetitive row data" under the hub column. Isn't it hard to understand Richardissimo?

Comment: It's clear that you only want one row for each different value in the 'hub' column. However there are lots of other columns there. You have stated in the question "without affecting the other columns of the tables". So taking the Name column as an example, there are 4 different values against hub1. So if there is only one row for hub1, what happens to those values, given that you don't want the other columns to be affected?